# Aggregating rows with rank or index >= N

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a query that joins my customers and transactions table, lets alias this joined query as `jq`. I want to create a ranking of each customer's purchases (transactions) by order timestamp (`order_ts`). So I did,

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       order_id, 
       order_ts, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_ts ASC), 
       amount 
FROM jq GROUP BY customer_id 
        ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Now, I want 5th purchases onwards to be an aggregated single row instead of 5th, 6th, 7th, and so on. The summed row will retain the 5th's `order_id` and `order_ts`. How do I do this in MS SQL Server and Postgres?

Comment: What would be the value for `order_id` and `order_ts` after the aggregation?

Comment: some sample data and exptected result please . ..

Comment: @FelixPamittan I've updated the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can achieve this with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT customer_id,min(order_id),min(order_ts), CASE WHEN rnk < 5 then rnk else 5 end as rnk,sum(amount)
FROM(
    SELECT customer_id, 
           order_id, 
           order_ts, 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_ts ASC) as rnk, 
           amount 
    FROM jq)
GROUP BY customer_id,
         CASE WHEN rnk < 5 then rnk else 5 end
ORDER BY customer_id
```

This will group each rnk > 5 as 5, so as 1 group. I selected min order_id,ts to select it form the 5th.

Comment: Great solution and more efficient. +1

Comment: SELECT customer_id,min(order_id),min(order_ts),**rnk**,sum(amount) ... GROUP BY **customer_id** , is there any issue, @sagi, My doubt is **rnk** is not included in GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks @FelixPamittan

Answer (score 3):

> **Though this produces the correct result, sagi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36303500/2203084) is more efficient.**

---

You can use a `SELECT` on the result and filter for `RANK < 5`. Then do a `UNION ALL` on the aggregated values for `RANK >= 5`

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT 
        customer_id, 
        order_id, 
        order_ts, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_ts ASC) AS rnk, 
        amount 
    FROM jq 
    GROUP BY customer_id 
)
SELECT
    customer_id,
    order_id,
    order_ts,
    rnk,
    amount
FROM Cte
WHERE rnk < 5

UNION ALL

SELECT
    customer_id,
    MIN(order_id),
    MIN(order_ts),
    MIN(rnk),
    SUM(amount)
FROM Cte
WHERE rnk >= 5
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

**This is for SQL Server*

Comment: You can do this selecting only one time from the jq.

Comment: Yup. This is just one of the many possible solutions. Less efficient than yours though.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, use an outer query to get the result

```
SELECT customer_id,(CASE WHEN ROW_NO <5 THEN ROW_NO ELSE 5 END) ROW_NO, SUM(amount) amount
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, 
           order_id, 
           order_ts, 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_ts ASC) ROW_NO, 
       amount 
FROM jq 
)   D
GROUP BY customer_id,(CASE WHEN ROW_NO <5 THEN ROW_NO ELSE 5 END)
```

Comment: Although its the correct way to go, you are not providing the correct output (id and date are missing)

Comment: u mean the *min(order_id),min(order_ts)* is a valid data for the SUM(Amount) GROUP BY customer_id.?

Comment: The min(order_ts) is valid for sure, the id not so much, but assuming bigger date means bigger id then yea.